# Submit specific model object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ViewModel containing the following objects:

- Person me
- `List<Person>` family

Now, on my View, I would like to be able to edit, not only my info but the info of my family (Name, DoB, Address, and so on).

I was considering to have a form that I could bind to the object 'me' and a form for each object in the family list. I have been looking everywhere and can't find a solution for this...

Comment: Do you want to edit everything on that one view or links to edit each family member that will take you to an edit page for them?

Comment: The ideal would be to edit everything in the same view.

Answer (score 3):

So, for your view model, create a view as such:

```
@model SomeViewModel
<div>
    <h3>Me</h3>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Me)
</div>
<div>
    <h3>My Family</h3>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Family)
</div>
```

Then, either in ~/Views/Shared or in the views folder for your controller create a folder named "EditorTemplates" and add a view in there named "Person.cshtml" and add code as such:

```
@model Person
<div class="person">
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</div>
    <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Dob)</div>
    <div>etc.</div>
</div>
```

The `@Html.EditorFor()` will then find the Person.cshtml partial view in the EditorTemplates folder and use that to render the HTML for each person.  Note that you use the exact same syntax for the single person "Me" and for the list of people "Family".  The EditorFor will create the control properly and index them in the ID/name (i.e. id='Family[0].Name', id='Family[1].Name', etc.).

Comment: Are you sure in your first snippet you don't mean `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Family)` ?

Answer (score 1):

For this scenario, I would simple suggest a partial.

```
@foreach (var member in Model.Family)
{
    <div class="family-member" id="@member.Id">
        @Html.Partial("_addEditFamilyMember", member)
    </div>
}
```

Partial my look something like this (needs better formatting but you get the idea):

```
@model StackOverflow.Models.Person

@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id) 
Edit Family Member:
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age)
```

You would need to wire up the save by iterating over each family member div and calling a save method via an $.ajax post.  To save unnecessary hits to the database, I would also track dirty changes by adding a "dirty" class to the family member div when I changed any field inside that container.  Then when you iterate over your family members to save, you will only select those that are "dirty".

On another side note, I would just have this entire view bound to a List and just include the "Me" record in that list of person records.  Since the "me" person is no different than the other members, why have it separate?  If you do need to designate that member as a primary member, then just create a "PersonType" property that you can use as a discriminator.